# get access token from URL to execute an API on submit with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, access-token, loopbackjs

this is the url of the page where i want to get the access token from and set it to execute the api on submit :

```
http://localhost:3001/reset-password?access_token=RLMVvTsmcxB5g9laDn6TENhx7ggFzG5ammKlGrMHoqAsuc0P1PA7z0mZgtGcISMq
```

this is the handlesubmit of this page :

```
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      console.log("values", values);
      //this.loginUser(values);    
      if (!err) {
        this.props.showAuthLoader();
        this.props.userReset(values);

      }
    });
  };
```

this is the service where I am executing the api

```
const resetPassword = async (newPassword) => {

    const user = localStorage.user;
    const accessToken = user ? JSON.parse(user).id : '';
    const wsResponse = await axios.request({
        method: 'post',
        // url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/users/reset',
        url: `${endpointReset.USER_Reset}?access_token=${accessToken}`,
        data: {
            newPassword,
        }
    });
    return wsResponse;
}
```

When I execute it now I am getting 401 authorization required and that's obvious because the api is executed without access token.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am using loopback for backend on port 3000 and react on port 3001. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you can use 
    var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("c");
console.log(c);

Comment: where can i use that exactly can you detail a bit more ?

Comment: you can say that i can access token from url and put it in the api so you can get

Comment: you can search on it google how to get parameter from url